# Getting price at each week

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a simple table:

```
prices(fromwhichweek(int),newprice(int))  
data example:  
1,20  
3,21 
10,30
```

So im looking for an sql statement(s) which returns What are prices at each week?
Something like(according to 3 rows above):

```
1,20  
2,20  
3,21  
4,21  
5,21  
6,21  
7,21  
8,21   
9,21  
10,30
...
```

Comment: is your expected result based on your sample input? if so, you have a bit more explaining to do

Comment: It looks like the goal here is to fill in missing weeks with the prior week's price.  But how do we know what range of weeks is requested?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could create a table populated with 1-52 weeks.

```
create table weeks (week int);
insert into weeks values (1), (2), ....(52);
```

Then you can execute the following query to get the result.  This is a native MYSQL query.  You may need to change it slightly if you are using a different sql vendor.

```
select A.week, B.price from weeks as A, prices as B where 
    B.fromwhichweek = (select C.fromwhichweek from prices as C where 
                       C.fromwhichweek <= A.week order by C.fromwhichweek desc limit 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a sequence of weeks.  The following version gets the price by using a correlated subquery in the `select` statement:

```
select w.week,
       (select top 1 newprice from prices p where w.week >= p.fromwhichweek
        order by fromwhichweek desc
       ) theprice
from (select 1 as week union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
      select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all
      select 9 union all select 10
     ) w
```

Some comments.  This depends on having a list of the weeks.  Here it is done with an explicit subquery.  Depending on the database, there are other methods.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I think I might be going blind.  That tag was repeated three times and I managed to miss it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that will determine the number of weeks required dynamically, based on the highest `fromwhichweek` value in the table. You can extend beyond that by assigning the value to `@end` explicitly (e.g. try with 22 or 25) instead of using `MAX`. This should scale OK with 52 weeks presuming that your prices table is really this simple.

```
DECLARE @prices TABLE(fromwhichweek INT, newprice INT);

INSERT @prices VALUES
(1, 20),  
(3, 21), 
(10,30);

DECLARE @start INT, @end INT;

SELECT @start = MIN(fromwhichweek),
       @end   = MAX(fromwhichweek)
FROM @prices;

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (@end-@start+1) 
    n = @start-1+ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
  FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT fromwhichweek = x.n, 
  newprice = COALESCE(p.newprice, (
    SELECT TOP (1) newprice FROM @prices 
    WHERE fromwhichweek <= x.n
     AND newprice IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY fromwhichweek DESC))
FROM x 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN @prices AS p
  ON x.n = p.fromwhichweek
ORDER BY x.n;
```

Answer (score -1):

This will give you the output you said you wanted.  If you want something different, modify your question :)

```
SELECT
  fromwhichweek, price
FROM
  prices
ORDER BY
  fromwhichweek ASC
```

Comment: your example data shows only one occurrence of 'fromwhichweek'.  are there multiple 'fromwhichweek's with different 'price's?  post some more sample data if you would like a more feasible answer.

Comment: example've been edited. There is only one occurrence of 'fromwhichweek'. The main goal is to get What price is at a week, because there is an another table with orders and there are which week,which person what ordered, like this:  
person1,1(week),1(day),whatordered;     
person1,1(week),2(day),whatordered;     
person1,1(week),3(day),whatordered;     
person1,2(week),1(day),whatordered;     
person1,2(week),2(day),whatordered;     
and i want to know how much a person1 have to pay at each day(stored in prices.newprice) i hope i clarified the problem